# 3 Q's in 1. While loops, class issue, calling another class's function

Tags: class, while-loop, reference

I am trying to do generate a random number and if it is <= 1, it will spawn an `astroid` (yes I know it is spelled wrong, but it's all over my code so I don't want to change it now). But I'm having trouble. I just learned some C# to code a game in unity for my final project in HS computer science. On the while loop itself I am getting:

> "Invalid token 'while' in class, struct, or interface member declaration".

In the `while` condition, I am trying to check a bool variable called `isDead` in my player class. The error says it is a field but used like a type. And then the class is ending at the while loop even though the brackets match up (that I know of, I'm used to C++) and that is causing the `spawnStuff()` function to not work. I'm sorry if these are simple questions but I couldn't find any answers that fix my problems from other sites. And the Unity forum deleted my post.

using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

```
public class CallSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform astroid;
    public Vector3 position;

    while (Player.isDead == false)
    {
        bool generate()
        {
            int rnd = Random.Range(0, 10);
            if (rnd <= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
        void spawnStuff()
        {
            if (generate() == true)
            {
                position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-30.0F, 30.0F), 20, Random.Range(0.0F, 0.0F));
                Instantiate(astroid, position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Um, is it just me, or is your `while` loop in class, *outside* any method?

Comment: And if you're used to C++, I'm not sure why you'd think that's ok, because it certainly isn't ok in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Unity but I understand C#, and the while loop is outside the context of a method. The log says that the class is ending at the while loop because you are returning a value. In other words, the while loop should be inside the function, not the other way around. The next code has the least number of changes in order for it to work.

```
public class CallSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform astroid;
    public Vector3 position;

    bool generate()
    {
        int rnd = Random.Range(0, 10);
        if (rnd <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }        
    }

    void spawnStuff()
    {
        while (Player.isDead == false)
        {
            if (generate() == true)
            {
                position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-30.0F, 30.0F), 20, Random.Range(0.0F, 0.0F));
                Instantiate(astroid, position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it accomplishes what you need to do but at least you can get the code to work and maybe figure out what the next step should be. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know what I was thinking, that was a really stupid oversight on my part. I made it more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks for the help!